# Encoding type of HEX

Tags: c++, c, hex, decode, encode

Here's an encoded memory address

```
9867640
```

actual hex address (decoded):

```
0x969178
```

how is it encoded ? .. I tried ascii but doesn't seem like it

Comment: What makes you think it's "encoded" at all?  Where is it coming from?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Conversion

Comment: Looks like the decimal equivalent to the hexadecimal "decoded" value..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a basic misconception of the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with encoding.

The first string shows the value in decimal system (base 10), the second string shows the value in hexadecimal system (base 16, as indicated by the `0x`).

Answer (score 4):

This is not encoding rather representation.

The first one is **decimal( BASE 10)** representation
`9867640` = `9` `8` `6` `7` `6` `4` `0` = `9`x10^6 **+**`8`x10^5 **+** `6`x10^4 **+** `7`x10^3 **+** `6`x10^2 **+** `4`x10 **+** `0`x10^0

The second one is **Hexadecimal( BASE 16)** representation
`0x969178` = `9` `6` `9` `1` `7` `8` =  `9`x16^5 **+**`6`x16^4 **+** `9`x16^3 **+** `1`x16^2 **+** `7`x16 **+** `8`x16^0

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to move from Hexadecimal base to decimal base you just multiply each digit with 16^n,

when n is the "place" of the digit in the number (starting from 0).

0x969178 becomes 8*16^0 + 7*16^1 + 1*16^2 +...